# Mongodb database hosting limitations and options

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongodb-atlas

So I'm currently working on an application in node js and I'm using mongodb as the database for the server, it all went well until I got to the point of hosting the database.
I've came across mongodb atlas which seems to be the most popular option BUT I noticed a few things:

- For **dedicated servers** the max connections limit is set to 1500 for the cheapest one which is kind of low especially when a single user connected to the server can have up to 5 connections **(Set by mongoose)** so It can easily exceed 1500 or 3000 or any other limit set by dedicated servers. *(4 users were testing the app the other day and we reached around 47 connections using M0 free cluster)*.
- **Serverless** option might seem cheap but the costs can easily exceed hundreds if not thousands of dollars if not properly monitored, plus the concept of RPUs and WPUs and how they're calculated is not really clear yet so no clue what to expect.

I'm really not sure what to go for or if there's any other option out there that's both cheaper and reliable *(I'm aware of VPS but not quite sure yet)*. Any opinion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What sort of apps?